# Use Cauchy Criterion for Series directly to prove that the series converges $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

So far I have:
I first did the Partial Fraction Decompositon to use for the proof. Assume $\epsilon > 0$ and there exists $N$ in the naturals such that $1/N < \epsilon$. WLOG, assume $n > m > N$.

$$  \sum_{j=k}^{n} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)} $$
and I see that it is a telescoping series and am left with the first and last term. then i see that the value leaves me with less than $0.5/2k-1$ but I am stuck here.

Comment: Is the sum starting at $k$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $1<N\epsilon $. Then for all $N\leq m\leq n$ we have

$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}-\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}\right|$$

$$=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}\right|=\sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}<\sum_{k=N}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}$$

However, this sum is easy to write in a compact form as it is an [alternating series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%2F%28%282k%2B1%29%282k-1%29%29%2Ck%2CN%2Cn%29):

$$=\frac{n-N+1}{(2n+1)(2N-1)}\leq \frac{N-N+1}{(2n+1)(2N-1)}=\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2N+1)}<\frac{N}{(2n-1)(2N+1)}\epsilon$$

Since the denominator of this fraction is greator than the numerator, we conclude

$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}-\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}\right|<\epsilon$$

Thus, the sequence of partial sums is Cauchy and therefore converges.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left|\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)} \right| =  \sum_{k=m}^{n} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)} $$

You telescoped wrongly, or wrongly took a limit in $n$. What you wrote would be correct if it was $\sum_{k=\bbox[orange]{1}}^\bbox[orange]{m}$ but it should be $\sum_{k=\bbox[orange]{ m+1}}^\bbox[orange]{n}$. Also the LHS you wrote $\sum_{k=1}^{\bbox[orange]{\infty}}$ which is not equal to the difference of partial sums on the RHS. For $n>m$,
$$  \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}  -  \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}\right|  = \frac12\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\left(\frac1{2k-1} - \frac1{2k+1} \right)=\frac12\left(\frac1{2m+1}-\frac1{2n+1}\right)$$
which you should be able to finish.

Comment: please recheck the problem I mistakenly wrote the equals sign which may have cause you to interpret it wrong and it should read j=k not m. I did get my PFD to be what you wrote which is the 1/2(1/(2m+1)−1/(2n+1)) @Calvin Khor

Comment: @Queen that part is not so important but I would rather you didn't change parts of the question that would make what I wrote become nonsense. The important part is you said you ended up with $\frac{0.5}{2m}-1$ which is not correct

Comment: @Queen with regards to finishing, if $n>m>N$,  can you give a good bound on $\frac1{2n+1}$ and $\frac1{2m+1}$?

Comment: Thanks  so much I see it I was able to !